# jquery how to stop animation if last element reached

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a horizontal scroller.
How to stop animations when last element reached?

Using offset? width? position?...

How to achieve to stop any animation if there is no more elements to display?
But allowing to go back?

I have two buttons: PREV and NEXT; this buttons allow the user to view pages.
There are 7 pages starting from page 4.

Thanks in advance

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vkNg4/5/)

```
$('#page_holder').animate({left: '-=546px'}, 0);

$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('#page_holder').animate(
    {left: '+=182px'},{
    duration: 1000, 
    easing: 'easeOutBack'
    });
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    $('#page_holder').animate(
    {left: '-=182px' },{
    duration: 1000, 
    easing: 'easeOutBack'
    });
});
```

Comment: You must have a way to count the elements - either server side or javascript. With array is easy to iterate the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's already an `overflow-hidden`, parent we can change it's `scrollLeft` position:

***[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vkNg4/98/)***

```
var $par = $('#container').scrollLeft(546) ; // Get the element that has CSS overflow
                                             // and set to initial position
$('.prev, .next').click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();                      // Prevent default Anchors behavior
    var n = $(this).hasClass("next") ? "+=182" : "-=182"; // Direction
    $par.animate({scrollLeft: n});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/vkNg4/2/

```
var cur = 1;
var max = $(".page").length+1;

$('#page_holder').animate({left: '-=546px'}, 0);

$('.ll').click(function(){
    if (cur-1 < 1) return;
    cur--;
    $('#page_holder').animate(
    {left: '+=182px'},{
    duration: 1000, 
    easing: 'easeOutBack'
    });
    alert(cur);
});


$('.rr').click(function(){
    if (cur+1 > max) return;
    cur++;
    $('#page_holder').animate(
    {left: '-=182px' },{
    duration: 1000, 
    easing: 'easeOutBack'
    });
    alert(cur);
});
```